What exactly was so wrong with Amalek's actions?
Given their southern proximity to Canaan, wasn’t Amalek justified in perceiving itself as a potential target of Israelite conquest? In the context of (what they may have perceived as a defensive) war, isn’t it considered strategic to press an advantage?

What's the issue you have with the commentaries? Or, why do you exclude them?

It is worth mentioning that Yaakov Avinu our ancestor, did the same thing to Esav their ancestor: He got the bechorah from him when he was tired, עייף. Indeed, those are the only appearances of the word עייף in the Torah.

What you refer to as Amalek and the Philistines were a colony of a surviving remnant from the Minoan civilization. They were a seafaring nation based primarily in the Aegean Sea that were almost entirely wiped out through the act of G-d with the eruption of Santorini/Thrace. Although military strong, their culture was depraved including child sacrifice and human trafficking.

First, the Amalekites were cowards.  They attacked without provocation weak refugees untrained for war who were just passing through.  They attacked them from the rear, including their women and children.
Second, Amalek was first in a long line of antisemites and represents them all.  He was the archetypal enemy of the Jews. The injunction to uproot him really applies to all antisemites.
Third, the Midrash tells us that Amalek weakened the nations’ fear of God:

When Israel came out of Egypt, and God split the sea before them and drowned the Egyptians within it, the fear of Israel fell upon all the nations. But when Amalek came and challenged them, although he received his due from them, he cooled the fear of them for the nations of the world. [Midrash Tanhuma, Ki Tetze 9]

Finally, the Torah says: "The Lord will be at war with Amalek throughout the ages."  [Ex. 17:16]  That’s because God knew Amalek's heart.  It's not so much what Amalek did at that time, bad as it was.  It was really a war between the forces of good and the forces of evil, which takes place in every generation, and is therefore eternally relevant.

They also attacked the weak of the Jews, i.e. sick and tameim who walked outside clouds of glory.
